# All the classes in java belong to Object Class , then why can't a class be static

Tags: java, static

For a class being static, it is required it to be not a top level class. Since all classes belong to Object class which is the superior of all classes, then why can't we create a class with static keyword? Why is static classes allowed only in nested scenario.

Comment: What has the ability to have static or non-static only for nested classes to do with the fact that all types are sub-types of `Object`? Very unclear. If you simply want to know, why you cannot mark a top-level type as static, the (only) answer is: Because the language says so. But  it also makes sense. Nested classes are also members of their surrounding class. Top level classes are not.

Comment: "top-level class" doesn't mean the class doesn't extend another class, it means the class isn't _enclosed_ by another class (i.e. is not a member of another class).

Answer (score 0):

All the classes in Java (transitively) extend `Object`, they are not inner classes inside it.

`static` wouldn't mean anything for top level classes, and therefore is forbidden. For inner classes, `static` means the same thing it means for other members (such as data members and methods) - the inner class belongs to the outer class, not to a specific instance of it.